# How to delete html file whose first name contains particular word with batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have some html files :

```
pkg_mon_spt@id=6&page=1.html
pkg_mon_spt@id=7&page=1.html
pkg_mon_spt@id=8&page=1.html
pkg_mon_spt@id=6&page=2.html
pkg_mon_spt@id=7&page=2.html
```

my batch script to delete All files that contain the words "page=1" is:

```
@echo off
if exist *page=1.html del *page=1.html
pause
```

html files and batch file are in the same folder.
when i run the batch file , html file whose name contains the word "page=1" was not erased.

What is wrong? Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Why `IF EXIST`? Simple batch where there is that only this command, it is not necessary to include it. What I mean, it is `DEL` itself already checks if the file exists, it will not delete something that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

use quotes around your filenames (it contains special characters (`=`,`&`)):

```
if exist "*page=1.html" del "*page=1.html"
```

Comment: this does not make a difference sine the `&` does not occur literally in the path...

Comment: @aschimpfl: it's more the `=`: `del *page=2.html` - `*page konnte nicht gefunden werden`. Same problem/solution with the `if exist`.

Comment: I agree, the `=` is a separator for the command line interpreter just like SPACE, for instance;

Comment: +1 Double quoting _all_ file names seems to be the best practice. See [delimiters explanation](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

When your batchfile is in the same folder this command should be enough.

`del *page=1.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the pattern `*page=1` you are using, besides missing quotes. You can work around that using the `find` command:

```
for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%L in (
  'dir /B /A:-D "\path\to\folder" | find "page=1"'
) do (
  ECHO del "%%~fL"
)
```

To actually delete files remove the `ECHO`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

```
if exist *"page=1.html" del *"page=1.html"
```

thanks for helps and respons.